# Spark Scala UDF to count number of array elements contained in another string column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I have a spark dataframe df with 2 columns, say A and B, where A is array of string type and B is a string.

For each row, I am trying to count how many elements in A are contained in B.  The UDF I have written is as follows. I thought it should be easy but it breaks down in the subsequent action step.

```
val hasAddressInUDF = udf{(s: String, t: Array[String]) => t.filter(word => s.contains(word)).size}
```

Could anyone help?  Thanks.

Comment: Please share error message. Do you have null in your data?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the `Seq.count` method for this one: for each element in the sequence you can count whether it is a substring of your B column.

```
import spark.implicits._
val df = Seq(
  (Seq("potato", "meat", "car"), "potatoes with meat"),
  (Seq("ice", "cream", "candy"), "pasta with cream"),
  (Seq("crackers", "with", "hummus"), "tasty food")
).toDF("A", "B")

df.show(false)
+------------------------+------------------+                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
|A                       |B                 |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
+------------------------+------------------+                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
|[potato, meat, car]     |potatoes with meat|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
|[ice, cream, candy]     |pasta with cream  |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
|[crackers, with, hummus]|tasty food        |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
+------------------------+------------------+

def count_in_seq = udf((A: Seq[String], B: String) => A.count(elem => B.contains(elem)))

df.withColumn("counts", count_in_seq($"A", $"B")).show(false)
+------------------------+------------------+------+                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
|A                       |B                 |counts|                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
+------------------------+------------------+------+                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
|[potato, meat, car]     |potatoes with meat|2     |                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
|[ice, cream, candy]     |pasta with cream  |1     |                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
|[crackers, with, hummus]|tasty food        |0     |                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
+------------------------+------------------+------+
```

Hope this helps!